# What to do if there is only one data point in a cluster when using K-Means clustering?

Tags: cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, k-means, bisection

I am using bisecting K-Means which utilizes k-means with k=2 and I have encountered only 1 data point in 1 cluster. Does that mean that the K-Means process should stop because it has reached convergence or should I start the algorithm process all over again with new values?

Comment: See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to let community to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1-element clusters occur quite frequently in k-means on dirty data.

Because k-means minimizes **squared errors**, assigning outlier points to their own cluster gives "optimal" results with respect to the squared errors objective. So this often *is* the correct result - it's just not what the user really *wanted*. Often the user would have preferred a non-squared optimization (e.g., using PAM), or a method that has a notion of "noise" points that do not belong to a cluster (e.g., DBSCAN).

Comment: That does not really answer the question. what should I do with the results

Comment: Then you may need to clarify your question better. You don't need to do anything with the results?